# Change image with jquery using .toggle() in same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I actually know how to change images with Jquery but the following case got me really stucked.
So I have a `div` I'm showing on image click like this:

```
$(dcoument).ready(function() {
    $('.image').click(function() {
        $('.element').toggle();
        $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
    });
};
```

Someow `.attr()` function doesn't work in this case and I have no idea why, I even have a function with changing to this specific image on hover like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').hover(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png');
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', 'image1.png');
    });
}
```

which works just the way it should. Any thoughts why code I posted can't change image on click? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you misspelled `document` in `$(dcoument).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add condition to by using hasClass.

```
<img src="image1.png">
<button>change</button>

$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
    if($('img').hasClass('fb')) {
        $('img').removeClass('fb');
        $('img').attr('src', 'http://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png');
    } else {
        $('img').addClass('fb');
        $('img').attr('src', 'http://www.thebloodycure.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/FaceBook-Logo-200x200.png');
    }
  });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c84kouny/1/

Comment: This is correct answer, thank you for investing your time in my problem's solving. I was able finding an issue, it's because of my previous hover function, I played around with classes and got it working.

Comment: Thats great. You can code whatever you're comfortable with. Welcome.